# PHP Signup from returns to wrong URL instead of index, Database error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I currently have a loginsystem where a user is able to register and login as a user.

When the user is logged in they should be able to upload a profile image.

The problem that i have is that when i press the Signup button, i gets rediretec to this URL (http://localhost/php51/login.php) Instead of this (http://localhost/php51/index.php).

The thing is that when the user has been registered, then the user should pop up on index.php and show a default profile pic for the user.

Instead i just get a blank page on (http://localhost/php51/login.php).

This is my database with the columns:

I have two tables in my Database called (loginsystem)

the two tables are:

table "profileimg" with the columns (id, status, userid)

and the table "users" with columns (user_email, user_id, user_name, user_password, user_phone, user_zip)

This is my code:

```
INDEX.php

    <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh.php';
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>


    <?php
// Check if there is users
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['user_id'];
        $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'";
        $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
        while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
          echo "<div>";
            if($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
              echo "<img src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg'";

            } else {
              echo "<img src='uploads/profiledefault.jpg'";
            }
            echo $row['name'];
          echo "</div>";
        }

      }

    } else {
        echo "No registered users :";
    }


    //Her checker vi for om man er logget ind, 
    //og viser herefter upload FORM

      if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['id'] == 1) {
          echo " You are logged in!";
        }
        //If the user is logged in, we allow the user to upload a profile image
        echo "<form action = 'upload.php' method='POST' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
          <input type = 'file' name = 'file'>
          <button type = 'submit' name = 'submit'>UPLOAD FILE</button>
        </form>";
      } else {
        echo " You are not logged in!";

        echo "<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name'>
        <input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='phone'>
        <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='email'>
        <input type='text' name='zip' placeholder='zip'>
        <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
        <button type ='submit' name='submitSignup'>Signup</button>
      </form>";
      }
    ?>


    <!--We use HTML forms when we want to upload images or files-->
    <!--The form HAS to be set as a POST method, and it needs the "enctype" attribute, which specifies that the content we are submitting using the form is a file-->


    <p> Login as user </p>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="submitLogin"> Login  </button>
    </form>


    <p> Logout as user </p>
    <form action="logout.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name = "submitLogout">Logout</button>
        </form>

</body>

</html>


LOUGOUT.php

    <?php

session_start();

session_unset();

session_destroy();

header("Location: index.php");


UPLOAD.php

    <?php
  //First we check if the form has been submitted
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Then we grab the file using the FILES superglobal
    //When we send a file using FILES, we also send all sorts of information regarding the file
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    //Here we get the different information from the file, and assign it to a variable, just so we have it for later
    //If you use "print_r($file)" you can see the file info in the browser
    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];
    //The "tmp_name" is the temporary location the file is stored in the browser, while it waits to get uploaded
    $fileTempName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];

    //Later we are going to decide the file extensions that we allow to be uploaded
    //Here we are getting the extension of the uploaded file
    //First we split the file name into name and extension
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    //Then we get the extention
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    //Here we declare which extentions we want to allow to be uploaded (You can change these to any extention YOU want)
    $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf");

    //First we check if the extention is allowed on the uploaded file
    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
      //Then we check if there was an upload error
      if ($fileError === 0) {
        //Here we set a limit on the allowed file size (in this case 500mb)
        if ($fileSize < 500000) {
          //We now need to create a unique ID which we use to replace the name of the uploaded file, before inserting it into our rootfolder
          //If we don't do this, we might end up overwriting the file if we upload a file later with the same name
          //Here we create a unique ID based on the current time, meaning that no ID is identical. And we add the file extention type behind it.
          $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
          //Here we define where we want the new file uploaded to
          $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
          //And finally we upload the file using the following function, to send it from its temporary location to the uploads folder
          move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);
          //Going back to the previous page
          header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else {
          echo "Your file is too big!";
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file, try again!";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
  }


SIGNUP.php

    <?php

include_once 'dbh.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, phone, email, zip, password) 
VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$zip', '$password')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND phone='$phone'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $userid = $row['user_id'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status) 
            VALUES ('$userid', 1)";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            header("Location: index.php");


    }

} else {
    echo "Error";
}


DBH.PHP

    <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginsystem");


LOGIN.PHP

    <?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;

    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Your login form seem to have action set on login.php while i can only see that you have file called signup.php

Comment: @Alex I just added the code for Login.php i forgot it woops :)

Comment: What about echo "<form action='login.php' method='POST'> in your else statement.It has button with name='submitSignup' while on login page in order to be redirected to index.php  $_POST['submitLogin'] must exist.That would give you blank page

Answer (score 0):

In your file index.php you need to change the line

```
echo "<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
```

to

```
echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>
```

Right now you're sending your signup data to the wrong place